# How do I get Mono's System.Data.SqlClient binary?

Tags: sql-server, mono

I've downloaded the latest stable build of Mono for OS X (2.10.9 as of this writing), and I see the documentation for System.Data.SqlClient [here](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLClient), but after installing I can't find a System.Data.SqlClient.dll file. I can find System.Data.dll at /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Data.dll, but I don't see the one I'm looking for anywhere on my hard drive.

Is it not implemented in the version I've downloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The System.Data.SqlClient namespace lives inside the System.Data assembly. There is no System.Data.SqlClient.dll.

From the documentation you linked:

> Exists in namespace System.Data.SqlClient and assembly System.Data

Answer (score 0):

Get the assemblies' AssemblyInfo and check that to see from which file it was loaded

```
Connection cn = new Connection(); // from System.Data.SqlClient;
Assembly assembly = cn.getType().Assembly;
Console.WriteLine(assembly.Location);
```

or something like that.